# How to nest 100% height divs and maintain a bottom footer (Pure CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when it comes to nesting `divs` at 100% height. It happens that the footer is not as far down as I want, it remains above the bottom of the parent `div`.

I have reproduced what happens to me and this is what I want.

```
html,body,.container-main,main,main > .container-fluid{
    color:#fff;
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cazs/wkwa73b9/

But always with the `divs` in 100% height

http://jsfiddle.net/Cazs/ah56LLxe/

I colored and given structure to layout, to see more clearly what I want, I hope you understand that what I want is that every div within `main` to be 100% height and the footer to remain at the bottom of the parent `div`

Comment: You have to study bootstrap containers again I think. You first add a row and then a colum where you specify the width on each device (i.e. for each screen width), e.g. 2 columns with col-xs-12 col-sm-6, would display the 2 block always full width one after the other on smartphones and half width alongside each other on bigger screens

Comment: not if you have something to do ... but in this instance I'm not using bootstrap, bootstrap unused see such work should not seek to columns and rows but 3 layer upper not fit the width

Comment: Ok I thought you forgot to include it because you add container-fluid and it you use bootstrap you should only put rows inside and in rows only columns because bootstrap will set margins etc. and probably mess up things if you try to style with css

Comment: If, that I have in mind, but the example I add not use it if anyone can help fix, the footer that is "no man's land" then I can use it on bootstrap

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, can't you just put the footer in a normal div or in another container *after* the content container and then you just put a single row and some columns inside

Comment: Do you want the footer to always be visible, or only after scrolling past all the main content?

Comment: that more content aya 100% high moves

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kw0xvnb0/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to achieve something like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kw0xvnb0/) If you are planning on using bootstrap the entire structure you are building with will change. You should decide in advance if you plan on using bootstrap. I would suggest removing all of the classes that are not serving a purpose from your html as it will cause confusion down the road.

```
html,body,.container-main,main,main > .container-fluid{
color:#fff;
height:100%;
}
```

I personally would not use the above code as I typically try to keep `body, html` separate to prevent confusion.

**EDIT**

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates how to accomplish what you want with some jquery [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jy9u7px1/1/).

Here is a fiddle showing how something similar can be accomplished using only css incorporating table properties. [DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/bd6swdpL/)

Comment: something like your demo's what I'm trying to find, but in your case you have chosen to remove the main .container-height: 100%; and give a high fixed "one, two, three"
The problem I'm seeing when I define in container-main me 100% to 100% fits window height "browser", but does the amount of scrolling, here comes the problem.
Maybe it's a bug?
If I have a 968px wide monitor the parent div is set to 968px

Comment: Whether this is exactly what I want, but without using Jquery, only CSS would not be possible?

Comment: I have edited my answer with another possible solution.